# Did the Marshall Plan cause Western Europe's economic expansion after WWII?

Tags: macroeconomics

It is widely accepted, that the Marshall Plan had a major role in the economic recovery of Western Europe after the end of the Second World War.
The reality is that the total economic support was less than 7% of the [1946 GDP (PPP) of the region](http://knoema.com/HSWE/historical-statistics-of-the-world-economy-1-2008-ad?tsId=1000910). How could that have any statistical significance?

In the period between 1943 and 1945, the GDP (PPP) of Western Europe fell by more than 19%. So, was that caused because there was no Martial Plan then? :)

Before the Keynesians jump on the multiplier effect bandwagon, I would point out, that the US quantitative easing after the 2008 economic crisis was 3.5 trillion USD, which is 20% of the 2013 US nominal GDP.

Comment: I would say the main reason the GDP (PPP) of Western Europe fell by more than 19%  between 1943 and 1945 is, that the WWII continued until 8. May 1945.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Barry Eichengreen is one of my favourites for this period. So, I am just going to let him explain it.

From : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.207.1592&rep=rep1&type=pdf

> Our central conclusion is that the Marshall Plan did matter. But it
> did not matter in the way that the “folk wisdom” of international
> relations assumes. Milward (1984) is correct in arguing that Marshall
> Plan aid was simply not large enough to significantly stimulate
> Western European growth by accelerating the replacement and expansion
> of its capital stock. Nor did the Marshall Plan matter by financing
> the reconstruction of devastated infrastructure, for as we show below,
> reconstruction was largely complete before the program came on
> stream.
>
> The Marshall Plan did play a role in alleviating resource
> shortages. But this channel was not strong enough to justify the
> regard in which the program is held. By 1948 and the beginning of
> Marshall Plan aid bottlenecks were scarce, and markets were good at
> alleviating their impact. Rather, the Marshall Plan significantly sped
> Western European growth by altering the environment in which economic
> policy was made. In the immediate aftermath of World War II
> politicians who recalled the disasters of the Great Depression were
> ill-disposed to “trust the market,” and eager to embrace regulation
> and government control. Had European political economy taken a
> different turn, post-World War II European
>
> Wartime relief, post-World War II UNRRA aid, and pre-Marshall Plan
> “interim aid” may well have significantly speeded up the
> reconstruction process. ... recovery might have been hobbled by clumsy
> allocative bureaucracies that rationed scarce foreign exchange and
> placed ceiling prices on exportables to protect the consumption of
> urban working classes. Yet in fact the Marshall Plan era saw a rapid
> dismantling of controls over product and factor markets in Western
> Europe. It saw the restoration of price and exchange rate stability.
> To some degree this came about because underlying political-economic
> conditions were favorable (and no one in Europe wanted a repeat of
> interwar experience). To some degree it came about because the
> governments in power believed that the “mixed economies” they were
> building should have a strong pro-market orientation. Marshall Plan
> aid gave them room to maneuver in order to carry out their intentions:
> without such aid, they would have soon faced a harsh choice between
> contraction to balance their international payments and severe
> controls on admissible imports.
>
> To some degree it came about because
> Marshall Plan administrators it pressured European governments to
> decontrol and liberalize even when they wished to do otherwise. In
> post-World War II Western Europe the conditions imposed, formally and
> informally, for the receipt of U.S. aid encouraged the reductions in
> spending needed for financial stability, the relaxation of controls
> that prevented markets from allocating resources, and the opening of
> economies to trade. Marshall Plan “conditionality” pushed governments
> toward versions of the “mixed economy” that had more market
> orientation and less directive planning in the mix. While postWorld
> War II European welfare states and governments are among the most
> extensive in proportion to economic life in history, they are built on
> top of, and do not supplant or bypass, the market allocation of goods
> 5 and factors of production. The Marshall Plan should thus be thought
> of as a large and highly successful structural adjustment program.

Comment: It's a cute theory, only let down by not representing what actually happened, which was broadened social protection, socialised health care, and various nationalisations